# Why alias is infront of some methods in Pandas Library

Tags: python, pandas

After I import pandas library, how come some methods need the `pd` before while others don't ?

example: `pd.read_csv('df.csv')`

example 2: `df.head()`

Comment: You are importing the pandas python module.  From there you are calling methods that return python classes.  You can always do a print(type(some_variable)) to get a better idea of what you are working with.  Example, print(type(pd)) or print(type(df)).

Comment: `pd` is just a common contraction for `pandas`, e.g. `import pandas as pd`. `df` is just a common variable name for a `DataFrame`, e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame(...)`. `read_csv()` is a module function, hence `pd.read_csv()` `head()` is a class method on a `DataFrame` object, hence `df.head()` but these are just conventions and you can call them whatever you want... `import pandas; d_frame = pandas.read_csv(...); d_frame.head()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a library, you're using their built-in functions and classes. The `read_csv` function is part of the Pandas library, which will generate a pandas `DataFrame` class from that library. If you set this dataframe to a variable (for example, `df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')`), you now have a `DataFrame` object from the pandas library.

This variable `df` (which you created using a pandas function) has its own built-in functions which are defined in the `DataFrame` class. So when you call `df.head()`, you're calling a built-in head function in the dataframe, and the code may represent something like this:

```
Class DataFrame(...):
def __init__(self):
    ...
    ...
def head(self, n=5):
    return self.iloc[0:n]
```

So in a way, you're still using the pandas library, but because the functions are built into the object you've assigned to variable `df`, you don't need to worry about having to call the library every time.

Comment: so because I assigned a class to an object (the df variable), that object (df) uses the methods of that class i called upon ? is this logic right

Comment: Yep, completely! There are methods you might need to use on series that aren't built-in. For example, if you want to convert a column to a datetime format with a specific structure, Pandas won't let you do that on top of a column (eg `df['time'].to_datetime()`). You need to call a function called `pd.to_datetime` so you can have a line of code that looks like: `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%d %m %y')`

Comment: I understand when I create an instance of a class it now has those methods, however why am I able to create new objects from an instance and still be able to call those methods. For Example x=df[col 1].... x.groupby()